# How make divs next to each other?

Tags: css, html

My knowledge of css and html is fairly limited. I am trying to make tiles that contain an image and one line of text, and these tiles should go next to each other, then continue on the next line if the screen's width has been used.

[image: Example of what I need]

This image shows what I need. The blue areas are images, the text below it is horizontally aligned `center`. The tiles are 160px wide, their height depends on how long the text is, but should be at least 150px. I know I have to work with divs, obviously, but I can't really get any further than that.

Comment: you have to create a css class to the divs. Add float:left and they will do what you want. also add the height and width.

Comment: Maybe this? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FUkE/) You need to edit the sizes yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML**

```
    <div><img src=".jpg" width="110" />text</div>
      .
      .
      .
     <div><img src=".jpg" width="110" />text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    width:160px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:150px;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:8px;
    float:left
}
img{display:block; margin:0 auto}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pcpnM/1/)**

Resize the result part to see the effect

`min-height:150px` make default height as 150px

`height:auto` helps to extend the div based on the content.

`float:left` makes divs to sit next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this image gallery example in w3schools-

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp

Sample Code-

Html-

```
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="klematis_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm"><img src="klematis2_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm"><img src="klematis3_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm"><img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
```

Css-

```
div.img
{
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}   
div.img img
{
  display: inline;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
div.img a:hover img {border: 1px solid #0000ff;}
div.desc
{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Well W3schools has been a good resource until now for me and I had no issues but will definitely look into the site.

Comment: I think a lot of people started with W3Schools - although I agree that there are much better resources available now.

Comment: @Cdeez I was in exactly the same position. When I started, I learned stuff almost exclusively from W3Schools but now, as a member of SO and having much more experience, I find W3Schools' incorrectness and unwillingness to correct it terrible.

Comment: I totally agree that at a beginner level W3schools is a good source to learn HTML and css stuff (_I haven't tried others_) but yes there are several other sites these days which are much more informative.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LX6EY/

HTML

```
<div class="element">
    <p>Some content goes in here!</p>
</div>
<div class="element">
    <p>Some content goes in here!</p>
</div>
<div class="element">
    <p>Some content goes in here!</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.element { background: #666; border: 1px solid #000; color: #fff; float: left; height: 260px; padding: 20px; width: 210px; }
```

For more information about floats please see [here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), they're incredibly useful, and at the moment pretty vital to the layout of most websites.